# How to extract and trim the fasta sequence using biopython

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

Hellow everybody, I am new to python struggling to do a small task using biopython.I have two file- one containing list of ids and associated number.eg

id.txt

```
tr_F6LMO6_F6LMO6_9LE  25
tr_F6ISE0_F6ISE0_9LE  17
tr_F6HSF4_F6HSF4_9LE  27
tr_F6PLK9_F6PLK9_9LE  19
tr_F6HOT8_F6HOT8_9LE  29
```

Second file containg a large fasta sequences.eg below

fasta_db.fasta

```
    >tr|F6LMO6|F6LMO6_9LEHG Transporter
    MLAPETRRKRLFSLIFLCTILTTRDLLSVGIFQPSHNARYGGMGGTNLAIGGSPMDIGTN
    PANLGLSSKKELEFGVSLPYIRSVYTDKLQDPDPNLAYTNSQNYNVLAPLPYIAIRIPIT
    EKLTYGGGVYVPGGGNGNVSELNRATPNGQTFQNWSGLNISGPIGDSRRIKESYSSTFYV

   >tr|F6ISE0|F6ISE0_9LEHG peptidase domain protein OMat str.  
    MPILKVAFVSFVLLVFSLPSFAEEKTDFDGVRKAVVQIKVYSQAINPYSPWTTDGVRASS
    GTGFLIGKKRILTNAHVVSNAKFIQVQRYNQTEWYRVKILFIAHDCDLAILEAEDGQFYK

   >tr|F6HSF4|F6HSF4_9LEHG hypothetical protein,  
    MNLRSYIREIQVGLLCILVFLMSLYLLYFESKSRGASVKEILGNVSFRYKTAQRKFPDRM
    LWEDLEQGMSVFDKDSVRTDEASEAVVHLNSGTQIELDPQSMVVLQLKENREILHLGEGS


   >tr|F6PLK9|F6PLK9_9LEHG Uncharacterized protein mano str. 
   MRKITGSYSKISLLTLLFLIGFTVLQSETNSFSLSSFTLRDLRLQKSESGNNFIELSPRD
   RKQGGELFFDFEEDEASNLQDKTGGYRVLSSSYLVDSAQAHTGKRSARFAGKRSGIKISG
```

I wanted to match the id from the first file with second file and print those matched seq in a new file after removing the length(from 1 to 25, in eq) .

Eg output[ 25(associated value with id,first file),  aa removed from start, when id matched].

fasta_pruned.fasta

```
>tr|F6LMO6|F6LMO6_9LEHG Transporter     
LLSVGIFQPSHNARYGGMGGTNLAIGGSPMDIGTNPANLGLSSKKELEFGVSL
PYIRSVYTDKLQDPDPNLAYTNSQNYNVLAPLPYIAIRIPITEKLTYGGGVYV
PGGGNGNVSELNRATPNGQTFQNWSGLNISGPIGDSRRIKESYSSTFYV
```

Biopython cookbook was way above my head being new to python programming.Thanks for any help you can give.

I tried and messed up. Here is it.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Seq

f1 = open('fasta_pruned.fasta','w')


lengthdict = dict() 
with open("seqid_len.txt") as seqlengths:
    for line in seqlengths:
        split_IDlength  = line.strip().split(' ')
        lengthdict[split_IDlength[0]] = split_IDlength[1]


with open("species.fasta","rU") as spe:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(spe,"fasta"):
        if record[0] == '>' :
            split_header = line.split('|')
            accession_ID = split_header[1]
            if accession_ID in lengthdict:
                f1.write(str(seq_record.id) + "\n")
                f1.write(str(seq_record_seq[split_IDlength[1]-1:]))



f1.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has almost everything except for a couple of small things which prevent it from giving the desired output:

- Your file `id.txt` has two spaces between the id and the location. You take the 2nd element which would be empty in this case.
- When the file is read it is interpreted as a string but you want the position to be an integer

  ```
  lengthdict[split_IDlength[0]] = int(split_IDlength[-1])
  ```
- Your ids are very similar but not identical, the only identical part is the 6 character identifier which could be used to map the two files (double check that before you assume it works). Having identical keys makes mapping much easier.

  ```
  f1 = open('fasta_pruned.fasta', 'w')

  fasta = dict()
  with open("species.fasta","rU") as spe:
      for record in SeqIO.parse(spe, "fasta"):
          fasta[record.id.split('|')[1]] = record

  lengthdict = dict() 
  with open("seqid_len.txt") as seqlengths:
      for line in seqlengths:
          split_IDlength  = line.strip().split(' ')
          lengthdict[split_IDlength[0].split('_')[1]] = int(split_IDlength[1])

  for k, v in lengthdict.items():
      if fasta.get(k) is None:
          continue
      print('>' + k)
      print(fasta[k].seq[v:])
      f1.write('>{}\n'.format(k))
      f1.write(str(fasta[k].seq[v:]) + '\n')

  f1.close()
  ```

Output:

> ```
> >F6LMO6
> LLSVGIFQPSHNARYGGMGGTNLAIGGSPMDIGTNPANLGLSSKKELEFGVSLPYIRSVYTDKLQDPDPNLAYTNSQNYNVLAPLPYIAIRIPITEKLTYGGGVYVPGGGNGNVSELNRATPNGQTFQNWSGLNISGPIGDSRRIKESYSSTFYV
> >F6ISE0
> LPSFAEEKTDFDGVRKAVVQIKVYSQAINPYSPWTTDGVRASSGTGFLIGKKRILTNAHVVSNAKFIQVQRYNQTEWYRVKILFIAHDCDLAILEAEDGQFYK
> >F6HSF4
> YFESKSRGASVKEILGNVSFRYKTAQRKFPDRMLWEDLEQGMSVFDKDSVRTDEASEAVVHLNSGTQIELDPQSMVVLQLKENREILHLGEGS
> >F6PLK9
> IGFTVLQSETNSFSLSSFTLRDLRLQKSESGNNFIELSPRDRKQGGELFFDFEEDEASNLQDKTGGYRVLSSSYLVDSAQAHTGKRSARFAGKRSGIKISG
> >F6HOT8
> ```

Comment: Thanks, @Maximilian Peters. It works well. Just wasn't able to write it to a file.

Comment: @Zero: I added the necessary lines for writing to a file as well

Comment: thanks for the help @Maimilian Peters. However, it showing error .              
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     f1.write(fasta[k].seq[v:] + '\n')
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: @Zero: converting it to `str` prevents the error, fixed the code, sorry, typed it on my phone without testing

Comment: when the `id.txt` file is tab-delimited files, the output file is empty.

Comment: You would need to split with '\t'